# How I can get the expiry date from a gpg key?

Tags: python-3.x, gnupg

I have created a gpg key with an expiry date (it has to expire in 1m), and when I want to display it in my python script, I get this :

```
Key expiry date :  1593681565
```

With this value, how I can know when the key will expire ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Python command you used but this looks like a Unix timestamp and this is very easy to convert.

The result from [www.epochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/) is: `GMT: Thursday, July 2, 2020 9:19:25 AM`

Converting from Python:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = 1593681565
datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 2, 11, 19, 25)
```